# What are the differences from an Oracle12C query and an Access one?

Tags: excel, odbc, oracle12c, recordset

If I have to run an Oracle12C query from Excel, I cannot write it anymore as I would write it in Access. And yet it would make sense to write it into Excel, because I could launch it directly from a VBA module, without having to copy paste between files.

Comment: This site requires a question and answer format. This just looks like an answer. Perhaps [edit] this part to be a question or original problem, and then post the answer in the answer space.

Answer (score 0):

The query remains mostly the same, a part few modifications:

- Access uses the notation *collection_table.column*. Change it into *collection.table.column*
- Access names aliases `table as tbl`: remove them (or put `table "tbl"`)
- Access uses square brackets: remove them (in case of spaces within names, put double quotes)
- Access accepts a date like `#11/22/2020#`. Change it into `TO_DATE('11/22/2020','mm/dd/yyyy')`
- Access has `IIf(condition1,true,IIf(condition2,...` . Use `CASE WHEN condition1 THEN true WHEN...`

Below an example of code:
(copy in a new module, go in *Tools*, *References...* and check *Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1*. You need to have a DSN defined in your ODBC connections: its name, username and password are here marked XXXX)

```
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlQry As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    sqlQry = "SELECT CASE WHEN CLL1.TBL1.CNY_CD IN ('CH','DE') THEN 'GERMANY' WHEN CLL1.TBL1.CNY_CD IN ('BE','FR') THEN 'WEST' END, " _
           & "CLL2.TBL2.WND_DATE, ROUND(AVG(ELEM1 + ELEM2),0) " _
           & "FROM CLL2.TBL3 INNER JOIN (CLL2.TBL2 INNER JOIN CLL1.TBL1 ON CLL2.TBL2.CTR_NR = CLL1.TBL1.OGZ_NR) ON CLL3.TBL3.OGZ_NR = CLL1.TBL1.OGZ_NR " _
           & "WHERE ((CLL3.TBL3 = PLN_DATE - 364) AND (ELEM3 = '0')) " _
           & "GROUP BY CASE WHEN CLL1.TBL1.CNY_CD IN ('CH','DE') THEN 'GERMANY' WHEN CLL1.TBL1.CNY_CD IN ('BE','FR') THEN 'WEST' END, CLL2.TBL2.WND_DATE " _
           & "HAVING ((CLL1.TBL1.CNY_CD In ('BE','CH','DE','FR')) AND (CLL2.TBL2.WND_DATE Between TO_DATE('10/3/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('1/2/2021','mm/dd/yyyy')))"
    Conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=XXXX;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX;": Conn.CommandTimeout = 0
    Conn.Open
    
    recset.Open sqlQry, Conn
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 9)).ClearContents 'delete previous data
    ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset recset 'copy data starting from cell A2
    recset.Close: Conn.Close
```

In this case, the functions TRIM, ROUND, AVG, and MAX had the same syntax both in Access and in Oracle.

Comment: A note on that `table "tbl"`. When dealing with aliases of queries (what in Access is `(SELECT .... ) AS Qry1` just write `(SELECT .... ) Qry1` without any quotation mark. Also, don't use double quotation marks for strings. "BE" will become 'BE'.